# Parameter from Text Input Box

Tags: excel, vba

What VBA code do I need for a pop-up text box saying "Enter A Name" such that this name would be pasted in three different places: `Sheets("Data").Select` in `A15` and `A50` (both hyperlinks that I don't want to mess up), and the third place is `Sheets("Run").Select`, which is a button.

All of the three places are called `Other 1` and I want to be able to change them with the enter information from the pop up.

```
Sub TestMacro() 
    Dim Name As String 
    Name = InputBox("Enter Name.") 
    Range("A" & 15).Value = Name 
    Range("A" & 50).Value = Name 
    Sheets("Run").Select 
    Range("A" & 1).Value = Name 
    Sheets("Data").Select 
End Sub
```

Comment: What have you tried? You're not very likely to find someone that will write your code for you.. for free! Show us your code and where you're stuck, then we can help :)

Comment: @pnuts [InputBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195768(v=office.11).aspx) would be better suited for getting user input :)

Comment: I need it to Select a button on sheet runSub TestMacro()
Dim Name As String
    Name = InputBox("Enter Name.")
    Range("A" & 15).Value = Name
    Range("A" & 50).Value = Name
    Sheets("Run").Select
    Range("A" & 1).Value = Name
    Sheets("Data").Select
End Sub

Comment: Lol I need it to select a Button on sheet run and Change that

Comment: What do you mean, select a button? change what exactly? What is your code not doing as expected?

Comment: This Code is Doing everything up till Sheet Select Run where I want it to Rename a button on that page the button is called Other 1

Comment: If that a Form or an ActiveX button? And you mean change the button's *caption*, not its programmatic *name* right?

Comment: Yes just the name you see when you click on it and i think its a activex button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've got something for you.

```
Sub TestMacro() 

    Dim Name As String 

    Name = InputBox("Enter Name.") 
    If StrPtr(Name) = 0& Then Exit Sub 'user cancelled out of inputbox!

    SetCellValue Sheets("Data"), "A15", Name
    SetCellValue Sheets("Data"), "A50", Name 
    SetCellValue Sheets("Run"), "A1", Name

    'Forms button can be accessed with the "Buttons" collection of "Worksheet" object:
    Sheets("Run").Buttons(1).Caption = Name 'assumes it's the first button in the collection

    'ActiveX button can be accessed directly by its programmatic name:
    Sheet1.CommandButton1.Caption = Name 'assumes sheet "Run" is Sheet1

End Sub

Private Sub SetCellValue(xlSheet As Worksheet, addr As String, value As Variant)
    xlSheet.Range(addr).Value = value
End Sub
```

Comment: `Sub Data_Button2_Click()
    
    Dim Name As String
    Name = InputBox("Enter Name.")
    Range("A" & 14).Value = Name
    Range("A" & 1052).Value = Name
    Sheets("Run").Buttons(23).Caption = Name




End Sub` Can't get it to run the last part

Comment: Feel free to upvote or accept if this answer helped! Not sure what this means... It's what `Sub TestMacro` now looks like? Note that you might get unexpected results if user cancels the `InputBox`.

Comment: Still cant get it to work that last line of code isnt working 'Sub Data_Button2_Click()
    
    Dim Name As String
    Name = InputBox("Enter Name.")
    If StrPtr(Name) = 0& Then Exit Sub
    Range("A" & 14).value = Name
    Range("A" & 1052).value = Name
    Sheets("Run").Select
    Sheets("Run").Buttons(23).Caption = Name




End Sub'

Comment: You need to make sure index `23` is correct, it looks good from here! Are you getting any error?

Comment: This Works Sub Data_Button2_Click()
    
    Dim Name As String
    Name = InputBox("Enter Name.")
    If StrPtr(Name) = 0& Then Exit Sub
    Range("A" & 14).value = Name
    Range("A" & 1052).value = Name
    Sheets("Run").Select
    ActiveSheet.Buttons("Button 24").Caption = Name




End Sub